# Java calendar problem, JDK 1.6.0.22

Tags: windows, calendar, java

I have a problem with getting the week of year. On my machine JDK 1.6.0.22 version is installed, on another machine 1.6.0.21. And both machines return different results:

> (1.6.0.22) week is: 1 
> (1.6.0.21) week is: 52

For this code:

```
      try {
         Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar();
         DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
         Date d = df.parse("2010-12-28 19:04:38 GMT");
         current.setTime(d);
         int currentWeek = current.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
         System.out.println("week is: "currentWeek);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Why does JDK 1.6.0.22 give the wrong result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This excerpt [from the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) explains why this difference can occur:

> Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR
>   field range from 1 to 53. **Week 1 for a
>   year is the earliest seven day period
>   starting on getFirstDayOfWeek() that
>   contains at least
>   getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days from
>   that year.** It thus depends on the
>   values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(),
>   getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of
>   the week of January 1.

And from the source code of `Calendar`:

> Both firstDayOfWeek and minimalDaysInFirstWeek are locale-dependent.

**So it's the locale that determines this, not the time zone!** Apparently, in some locales, week 1 of a year is considered to begin in the previous year. Try running this:

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(cal.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
    System.out.println(cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

I bet that either you're running the different versions in different locales, or the locale data changed between these versions. The result "1" could even be the more correct one and due to a bug fix in the locale data.

Comment: For example: Locale.US: week 1, Locale.GERMANY: week 52. The week in Germany starts on Monday, and on Sunday in the USA.

Comment: Right. But how would you explain for example this? `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US); Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20101226")); System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)); // 1 calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("AST")); System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)); // 52`

Comment: And I doesn't believe this is as per the IS) 8601 standard which says "Week 01 of a year is per definition the first week that has the Thursday in this year, which is equivalent to the week that contains the fourth day of January. In other words, the first week of a new year is the week that has the majority of its days in the new year"

Comment: @Balusc: Hm, that is strange. I get 52 printed twice, for both Java 1.6.0_21 and 1.6.0_22 running that code.

Comment: Oh? Well, that is weird (the whole `Calendar` thing is weird anyway). I'd be curious what others see. I'm running 1.6.0_22-b04 on Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the JDK date/time classes - use [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) instead.