# Java Calendar returns different dates

Tags: java

I do the following:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
int week = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

On my local machine my Timezone is Europe/Berlin. On my server it is UTC.
Running this code on local box returns week = 14. 
Running this code on my server returns week = 15.

I am out of ideas - can somebody explain that to me? This causes me big trouble :-(

Thanks for any pointers.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Are you certain you are getting different results?  From the code snippet it wouldn't matter at all what timezone it is in because you are manually setting the day and the hour of the day anyways.  This code would always return 15 in my mind.

Comment: Yes, I am extremly certain: I have copied this out of a Junit test. It runs local, but fails on my server. :-(

Comment: I think you've messed up your copy or your experiment somehow. If I run this code ([full copy](http://pastie.org/2972306)) on my machine, which is set to GMT/BST (BST as of that date), I get week = 14. Moreover, I don't see why being on Berlin time vs. UTC would matter in this case -- it's either 10:20 a.m. (Berlin) or 8:20 a.m. (UTC -- since Berlin would be on DST in April, it's +2 rather than +1), either way is still week 14.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java calendar problem, JDK 1.6.0.22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549027/java-calendar-problem-jdk-1-6-0-22)

Comment: @KevinCrowell: I don't think it's a duplicate (symptoms are too different). But that same issue could be the answer. Christian, what version(s) of the JDK does each machine have?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The OP of the duplicate question is incorrectly guessing that the JDK version is the problem. The issue, which is confirmed by the accepted answer for this question, is that the locales are different. That is the same answer for the duplicate question.

Comment: @KevinCrowell: Yes, but two different questions can have the same answer. The questions in this case represents different symptoms of a shared underlying problem, and having both improves the odds (to my mind) of someone finding the answer in the future.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The symptoms are the same in both cases: Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR is giving a different result on 2 different machines. A closed question would still show up in a search, and would point someone to a previous question with the correct answer.

Comment: @KevinCrowell: Closed questions can be deleted. But in any case, it's fine if there are two points of view on this. There are, in fact, probably more than two. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your Locale.  When having a de_DE java locale the week is 14, when having an en_US locale the week is 15.  Set both your machines to the same locale and they should work now.

I only tested my locale vs a German one, and could not find a reliable list online of which locales had the shifted week counting, but I'm certain this is the problem for you.

To see your locale programatically:

```
 Locale.getDefault();
```

To change your locale in Windows 7:

```
 Control Panel --> Region & Language --> Location Tab  --> Current Location
```

Comment: I suspect this is indeed what it is. @Christian, if I use [this code](http://pastie.org/2972365) which uses `Locale.GERMAN`, I get `week = 14`; but if I change my locale to U.S. using [this code](http://pastie.org/2972369), I get `week = 15`.

Comment: +1; but rather than changing the locale for the entire application, it might make more sense to just call `c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1)` (to get U.S.-style everywhere) or `c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7)` (to get German-style everywhere). This will depend on business needs, of course.

Comment: Ah minimal-days-in-first-week, nice.  This answer (or a new one) should describe that feature, which is definitely not obvious!

Comment: @ruakh: You don't have to change the locale for the entire application. See the links in my comment above, you just specify it when creating the `Calendar`.

Comment: My first tests show that this is what I have missed - thanks so much. I know do: Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"), Locale.GERMANY);